из массива чар в переменную string с++
Мне нужно в переменную String^ поместить массив char. Работаю в winform c++, пробовал System::Convert::ToString он выдает просто значение true;

Тебе простую строку? std::string varname = std::to_string(charstr) ? Или тебе нужны какие-то особые виды строки. Как-бы строки они разные в разных вариациях C++. В том-же Борланде используют макрос String varname(charstr);
У майкрософт в Visial Studio - ваще жесткая ваханабия твориться от версии к версии. В новых версиях это просто String varname = new String(charstr);

const char *a = "aaa";
String ^b = gcnew String(a);

